# Ortools - Routing - Setting different breaks for each vehicles

Tags: break, or-tools

Is there a way to set break time for each vehicle.  A code using SetBreakIntervalsOfVehicle doesn't work and results in solver hanging.

```py
    for v in range(data['num_vehicles']):
         vehicle_break = data['breaks'][v]
         break_intervals[v]= 
               [routing.solver().FixedDurationIntervalVar(
              15,100,vehicle_break[0],vehicle_break[1], 'Break for vehicle {}'.format(v))]
         time_dimension.SetBreakIntervalsOfVehicle(break_intervals[v], v, node_visit_transit)
```